# Read a textfile in C on Linux char by char

Tags: c, linux

I'm pretty new to C. Anyways for college i need to be able to read a textfile in C on Linux setting the O_DIRECT flag. I searched a lot but i only found solutions using the fopen() function though i have to use open(). It seems pretty complicated to me as a newcomer as far as programming is concerned. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: There are la multitude of example ans tutorials on how to use [`open`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html), [`read`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html), [`write`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) and [`close`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html) if you just search a little. And of course reading the [manual pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/index.html) will help a lot.

Comment: Well i made a lot of research the past days and I'm able to open and read the file now using the functions i have to. If I'm right, the O_DIRECT flag requires a storage allignment of 512 Bytes. So i need to use a special function to allocate my memory other than new, for example posix_memalign? I will have 2 buffers with a Size of 512 chars (512*8 Byte), so i can set the O_DIRECT flag. (2 buffers because i need to be able to get and unget chars and have to jump between the buffers when 512 characters are not enough to read the file). I hope i'm on the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Your homework is probably about implementing yourself some [buffering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer) on files (which is what `<stdio.h>` and `fopen` is doing for you).

You might use [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) with a count of one byte, but that is extremely inefficient. Practically speaking, you should pass a buffer of several kilobytes (e.g. 4Kb or 32Kb) to `read` and you should use the returned size to manage your buffer (and possibly advance some pointer into the buffer).

Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/). Perhaps study the implementation of libraries doing such buffering (both [GNU glibc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) & [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/) are free software implementations of [libc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library), so contain a `<stdio.h>` *implementation* that you could study).

Don't forget to compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Use the debugger (`gdb`) and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). With a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), use also other [`gcc` debugging options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) like e.g. `-fsanitize=address` etc.

Comment: Well, my homework is about building a compiler for a programming language. It's just a little bit annoying that i have so much trouble building the buffer, which is the smallest part of the whole work. I'll try to research more and hopefully finding a solution i can understand.

Comment: If you are not able to manage a buffer using `read`, you won't be able to build a compiler (which is much more difficult). It looks like you are lacking some programming skills that are expected from you. So work hard. Read several books. Study the source code of several software.

Comment: Unless you *need* to implement your own buffering (eg because your homework requires you too), it's generally easier (and better) to use `fdopen()` and then you can use the standard buffering that `fread()` etc implement.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is wrap the file descriptor you get with open in a struct of some sort (your own FILE struct) which includes a buffer.

Your own fread should first server the data from the buffer and only if there's none, it should call `read` to fill the buffer again and so on.

`man 2` is your friend. There are lots of options to all these system functions, but don't let that bother you too much. The gist of it is fairly simple.

Comment: Why not use `fdopen()` and then the standard `fread()`, rather than writing your own implementation of `fread`?

Comment: He says he has to use open and implement his own buffering.

Comment: He doesn't say he has to implement his own buffering - only that he has to use `open`. And in order to use `fdopen` you need to use `open` too, so that requirement is satisfied :)